# Ubuntu 13.10 does not load correctly

Tags: compiz

After tring to install the wizard feature of compiz, the ubuntu doesnt load up correctly. The only thing I can see is my background (the terminal doesnt work too).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The answer to your question is here: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).

Answer (score 0):

I think the link that Karel suggested is a great starting point.  I had this happen on a 12.04 version of Ubuntu and to fix it I had to re-install lightdm.  I'm not sure how it got uninstalled but that fixed it for me.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to follow that link but when I try to log in to my user using the Ctrl+Alt+F1 its says login failed.